# Fetching Facebook User Access Token Callback

Tags: java, spring, facebook, http, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch Facebook user access token as in the question title.
I configured my application, I am sending request to:

```
redirect:https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="+appId+"&redirect_uri="+REDIRECT_URI+"&response_type=token
```

and I always got response where there is a hashtag before first parameter:

```
/auth/fb/callback/?#access_token=blablabla
```

Does anyone know why Fb is keep adding the # before access_token??
I have hard time to parse this from HTTP request, as Spring shows me 0 GET parameters.

Is it possible to avoid this situation or parse with #???

Comment: Why is that "hard to parse"? It's standard URI syntax for a "fragment identifier".  Also, asking _"why"_ and getting an answer is unlikely to help you in any way.  It is what it is and you must deal with it if you want to use the API.

Comment: I don't get your comment. It's not a standard URI syntax, as # blocks the possibility to get parameters. Spring takes this as a null parameter list.

Comment: See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5 - notice this link itself contains a fragment identifier.

Comment: @JimGarrison: This is for client-side apps, which can then fetch the token from the fragment. But server-side apps need to request a code instead (that they can then go exchange for a token), because the hash part of the URL is not send to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know why Fb is keep adding the # before access_token?

Because you *asked* for it, by using `response_type=token`. You actually want to ask for a *code* instead.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#logindialog